# Update Marker on googleMap algorithm - android

Tags: java, android

The problem : In Android, for every 4 seconds, I will receive a ArrayList of Node(ArrayList < Node >) from the broadcast receiver and I have to update the location of markers individually based on the ArrayList just received (the title of the maker is Id) on the google map. The Node class is defined as:

```
Class Node{
      public String Id;
      public LatLng latlng;
      public Node(String Id, LatLng latlng){
          this.Id = Id;
          this.latlng = latlng;
      }
  }
```

At 0s , receive {A, B,}

At 4s , receive {A, C,}

At 8s , receive {B, C, D}

```
At 0s , receive {A, B,} : I will add these Nodes onto the Map individually.

At 4s , receive {A, C,} : then I have to update or remove them "individually"
A : update the location of marker A
B : remove marker B from the map
C : add marker C to the map

At 8s , receive {B, C, D} : then I have to update or remove them "individually"
A : remove marker A from the map
B : add marker B to the map
C : update the location of marker C
D : add marker C to the map
```

I have came up a solution by using two HashMap. Is there good algorithm can achieve updating the markers on the map individually ?

Answer (score 0):

I like this solution:

```
//MapPoint is your's Node
private Map<Long, MapPoint> mMovingPointsMap;

@Override
public void updateMovingPoints(Collection<? extends MapPoint> movingPoints) {
    for(MapPoint mapPoint : movingPoints){
        MapPoint pointOnMap = mMovingPointsMap.get(mapPoint.getId());

        if(pointOnMap == null){
            pointOnMap = mapPoint;

            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(pointOnMap.getLatitude(), pointOnMap.getLongitude());

            pointOnMap.setMarker(mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(latLng)
                    .title("Isso é um carro")));

            mMovingPointsMap.put(pointOnMap.getId(), pointOnMap);
        } else{
            Marker marker = pointOnMap.getMarker();
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(pointOnMap.getLatitude(), pointOnMap.getLongitude());

            LatLngInterpolator latLngInterpolator = new LatLngInterpolator.Linear();
            MarkerAnimation.animateMarkerToGB(marker, latLng, latLngInterpolator);
        }
    }

    for(MapPoint mapPoint: mMovingPointsMap.values()) {
        if(!movingPoints.contains(mapPoint)) {
             mMovingPointsMap.remove(mapPoint)
        }
    }
}
```

Explanation:

You have a Map with all your Nodes and the Id of your Nodes is the same of the Id of the Map (You can use HashMap). The you should receive your maps as an Iterable, not another Map. It will make your code more generic and scalable. You don't need to receive a Map from your server... All you need to do is to iterate to all new points and update/create points in the map that you already have.

Source: https://github.com/leandroBorgesFerreira/UpdatableMap

Edit:

As Luke Lin said, if you are looking for performance, this algorithm mat suit you better:

```
//MapPoint is your's Node
private Map<Long, MapPoint> mMovingPointsMap;

@Override
public void updateMovingPoints(Map<Long, ? extends MapPoint> movingPoints) {
    for(MapPoint mapPoint : movingPoints.values()){
        MapPoint pointOnMap = mMovingPointsMap.get(mapPoint.getId());

        if(pointOnMap == null){
            pointOnMap = mapPoint;

            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(pointOnMap.getLatitude(), pointOnMap.getLongitude());

            pointOnMap.setMarker(mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(latLng)
                    .title("Isso é um carro")));

            mMovingPointsMap.put(pointOnMap.getId(), pointOnMap);
        } else{
            Marker marker = pointOnMap.getMarker();
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(pointOnMap.getLatitude(), pointOnMap.getLongitude());

            LatLngInterpolator latLngInterpolator = new LatLngInterpolator.Linear();
            MarkerAnimation.animateMarkerToGB(marker, latLng, latLngInterpolator);
        }
    }

    for(MapPoint mapPoint: mMovingPointsMap.values()) {
        if(!movingPoints.contains(mapPoint)) {
             mMovingPointsMap.remove(mapPoint)
        }
    }
}
```

You can overload the method to have both approaches.

I hope I could help!

Comment: How about marker that appears previously and disappear presently.
Take 0s and 4s as an example:
Will your method remove marker B from the map right after 4s?

Comment: Check my new answer. A Collection is probably a better approuch

Comment: I agree on the first for loop, which looks great, but for the second for loop,  movingPoints in my case will be an ArrayList, which means that !movingPoints.contains(mapPoint) will cause me O(n). However, if I have two mMovingPointsMap: mOldMovingPointsMap and mNewMovingPointsMap, I can do if(! mOldMovingPointsMap.containsKey(mapPoint.id)). It will reduce my time from O(n) to O (1) for the second for loop.

Comment: You are right. You suggestion improves a lot the performance of the algorithm. I added another version of the algorithm with your ideas.

Comment: Thanks for writing out the code. I think it will work. However, I just wonder whether there is a better way to achieve the goal